problem with importing library of minecraft
import net.fabricmc.fabric.api.client.command.v1.ClientCommandManager;
import net.fabricmc.fabric.api.client.event.lifecycle.v1.ClientTickEvents;
import net.fabricmc.fabric.api.client.keybinding.v1.KeyBindingHelper;
import net.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient;
import net.minecraft.client.option.KeyBinding;
import net.minecraft.text.LiteralText;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW;

public class ModInitializer implements ModInitializer {

    private static KeyBinding keyBinding;
    private static boolean isClickerActive = false;
    private static int clicksPerMillisecond = 1;

    @Override
    public void onInitialize() {
       keyBinding = KeyBindingHelper.registerKeyBinding(new KeyBinding(
             "key.autoclickermod.toggle",
             GLFW.GLFW_KEY_UNKNOWN,
             "category.autoclickermod"
       ));

       ClientCommandManager.DISPATCHER.register(ClientCommandManager.literal("bind")
             .then(ClientCommandManager.argument("key", StringArgumentType.word())
                   .executes(context -> {
                      String keyName = StringArgumentType.getString(context, "key");
                      int keyCode = GLFW.glfwGetKeyScancode(GLFW.glfwGetKeyName(keyName));
                      keyBinding.setBoundKey(keyCode);
                      MinecraftClient.getInstance().player.sendMessage(new LiteralText("Bound clicker toggle to key: " + keyName), false);
                      return 1;
                   })));

       ClientCommandManager.DISPATCHER.register(ClientCommandManager.literal("cpms")
             .then(ClientCommandManager.argument("rate", IntegerArgumentType.integer(1))
                   .executes(context -> {
                      clicksPerMillisecond = IntegerArgumentType.getInteger(context, "rate");
                      MinecraftClient.getInstance().player.sendMessage(new LiteralText("Set clicks per millisecond to: " + clicksPerMillisecond), false);
                      return 1;
                   })));

       ClientTickEvents.END_CLIENT_TICK.register(client -> {
          while (keyBinding.wasPressed()) {
             isClickerActive = !isClickerActive;
             client.player.sendMessage(new LiteralText("Auto-clicker " + (isClickerActive ? "enabled" : "disabled")), false);
          }
          if (isClickerActive) {
             for (int i = 0; i < clicksPerMillisecond; i++) {
                client.mouse.click(MouseHelper.ClickType.LEFT);
             }
          }
       });
    }
}

I have problem with importing
net.fabricmc.fabric.api.client.command.v1.ClientCommandManager
and
net.minecraft.text.LiteralText
issues:
Cannot resolve symbol 'v1'
Cannot resolve symbol 'LiteralText'
im trying to write a clicker for minecraft but I cant solve this problem:\

What (if any) build tool are you using? How are you linking the dependencies? We need to see the configuration for that before we can help you

I use gradle for building, my gradle.properties:
Done to increase the memory available to gradle.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1G
org.gradle.parallel=true
Fabric Properties
check these on https://fabricmc.net/develop
minecraft_version=1.19.4
yarn_mappings=1.19.4+build.2
loader_version=0.15.11
Fabric API
fabric_version=0.87.2+1.19.4
Mod Properties
mod_version=1.0.0
maven_group=com.example
archives_base_name=mod

Can you please add your entire gradle.properties files on your question? (Sorry for the late reply I went on holiday and didn't have access to a computer)
